# Difference in rendered SVG fetched from FirefoxDriver and HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: javascript, svg, selenium-webdriver, highcharts

I am creating highchart graph using the following code in a HTML file using JQuery 1.8 and Highcharts 4.1.9.

```
<div id="JSGraphContainer" class="GraphContainerJS" "></div>
<script>
        $(function() {
                    var line;
                    var plotList= [];
                    data = {"vals": [['1244246400000', 11],
                                      ['1244332800000', 22],
                                      ['1244419200000', 11],
                                      ['1244505600000', 22],
                                      ['1244592000000', 33],
                                      ['1244678400000', 11],
                                      ['1244764800000', 22]
                                    ]};
                    $("#JSGraphContainer").highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'line',
                            zoomType: "x",
                            plotBorderWidth: 1,
                            plotBorderColor: 'black',
                        },
                        title: {text: null},
                        xAxis: {
                            crosshair: true,
                            type: 'datetime',
                            opposite: true,
                            tickmarkPlacement: "on",
                            gridLineDashStyle: "Dash",
                            gridLineWidth: 1,
                            tickWidth : 0,
                            plotLines: plotList,
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: { text: null },
                            tickAmount: 5,
                            gridLineDashStyle: "Dash",
                            opposite: false
                        },
                        series: [{  data: data.vals  }],
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {enabled : false},
                        tooltip: {
                            formatterdd: function() {
                                return ((new Date(this.x)).toDateString()) + ", " + this.y;
                            },
                            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span><b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
                            crosshairs: {
                                color: 'green',
                                dashStyle: 'solid'
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }); 
              </script>
```

My test code which is meant to extract generated SVG out for comparison purpose is

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.className("GraphContainerJS"));
String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", elem);
System.out.println(contents);
```

When I use FirefoxDriver then I get the correct SVG printed out to sysout but when I use JavaScript enabled HTMLUnitDriver, then I get the different SVG output which doesn't match firefox and doesn't render anything when copied on an html file. I tried to use firefox capabilities as

```
new HtmlLUnitDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```

but it doesn't help. I am hoping there must be a way to configure HtmlUnitDriver, if at all, to get the right output.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: there is already a method called getSVG in highcharts which can be used

Comment: Have you tried to disable **all** animations? Also, does FirefoxDriver supports SVG? And, do you have any errors? Have you tried with very simple chart? Like this: `$("#JSGraphContainer").highcharts({ series: [{ data: [10, 20] }] });`.

Comment: How do I disable all animations ? Are you taking about css3 methods ?        FirefoxDriver does support SVG and gives same content (svg) which is rendered over the browser (ff). since on HtmlUnitDriver being headless I cannot see anything nor I get any error. It is just when svg printed is again rendered on any other browser (by including it in html tags) then it shows blank canvas with just Highcharts.com watermark.

Answer (score 0):

there is already a method called getSVG in highcharts which can be used.

```
 svg = chart.getSVG()
       .replace(/</g, '\n&lt;')  
       .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/g10j2ymc/

Comment: Well the issue of difference in SVG output still remains. Running script on firefox gives different SVG content than generated using HtmlUnitDriver.